# Service account authentication with Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm building a server on top of MS Graph API and all I need to do is upload and download images to OneDrive. End users of the application will not access OneDrive directly nor will they all even have accounts. The files need only be accessible to the application itself and a handful of power users who do have their own credentials.

I would like to be able to just configure the credentials for a service account to be the only one accessing the bucket, but it seems all the auth flows require an end user to login. Is there an API-centric way to do this transparently? Or should I infer from the lack of explicit support that this isn't a valid use case for OneDrive and I should look at Azure Blob Storage?

Answer (score 0):

You can authenticate to MS Graph API with username + password using the class UserPasswordCredential (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.userpasswordcredential?view=azure-dotnet). Sample:

```
UserCredential creds = new UserPasswordCredential("fred@contoso.onmicrosoft.com","password");
var bearerToken = AcquireToken("https://graph.microsoft.com", "d1ddf0e4-d672-4dae-b554-9d5bdfd93547", creds).Result;

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + result.AccessToken);
var graphInfo = client.GetAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/").Result;
```

**Warning**: There are only few use cases where using username + password directly is legitimate (see http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/07/08/using-adal-net-to-authenticate-users-via-usernamepassword/). Additionally, UserPasswordCredential is not available in DotNetCore.